# Proof of Fundamental Lemma of Calculus of Variations

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Let me preface this question by saying I'm actually a physicist, not a mathematician, so a lot of the language I see you guys using here is over my head, so if you can keep it simple, that would be preferable.

The fundamental lemma of calculus of variations states that, if $f\in C^k[a,b]$, $\int_a^b f(x) h(x) dx = 0$,  and $h(a) = h(b) = 0$, then $\forall h \in C^k[a,b]$: $f(x) = 0$  $\forall x \in [a,b]$.

The proof of this usually goes something along the lines of assuming some specific form of $h(x)$, something like $h(x) = r(x)f(x)$ where $r(x) > 0$ on $(a,b)$ and $r(a) = r(b) = 0$, substituting this into the integral, and then proving that this for the integral to remain zero, this requires that $f(x) = 0$, and proof completed. My confusion is this: does this not only mean that the theorem holds for some small subset of $h$'s, namely, those fitting the form assumed to replicate the proof, rather than the general class of $h$'s proposed in the lemma above? The proof assumes that if you can demonstrate $f(x) = 0$ for some small subset of $h$'s, then it works for a larger class of $h$'s, which I have a hard time seeing as justified. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quoting the lemma wrong. It should be something like

> Assume $f\in\mathcal C^k[a,b]$ and that for all $h\in\mathcal C^k[a,b]$ which is zero at the endpoints it holds that $\int_a^b f(x)h(x)\,dx=0$. Then $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

In other words the $\forall h$ is in the *assumptions* of the lemma, not the *conclusion*.

The fact that only a certain few $h$s are used in the proof just means that the lemma *assumes more than it strictly needs to* -- which is to say that it *promises less* than it can keep. That can't make it *less* true than it would be if it listed precisely those $h$ that it needed the premise to hold for.

Comment: I understand that $\forall h$ is in the assumptions of the lemma, but when you conclude $f(x) = 0$ you only do so assuming certain things for $h$. In other words $f(x) = 0$ under more strict considerations than when the integral is 0.

Comment: @Joe: No, at the time you conclude $f(x)=0$, _there is no $h$ anymore_ because this conclusion is outside the scope of the quantifier $\forall h$. In order to _use_ the theorem you need to _supply it_ with proof that such-and-such hold for _all_ $h$, whether or not they have the special form the proof actuall uses.

Comment: How can the conclusion be outside the assumptions? And that's what I'm saying, we haven't proven it for all $h$, just those of the special form the proof actually uses.

Comment: @JoeHorne: Proving it for all $h$ is something _the user of the lemma_ has to do. The _proof of the lemma_ gets to take it for granted for every $h$ because it's an assumption!

Comment: In some sense you can view the lemma as having infinitely many different assumptions, one for each possible $h$ -- and they must _all_ be true before the lemma yields any conclusion to you. If you're looking to use the lemma, you need to establish the each of those assumptions. If it turns out that the _proof_ of the lemma only uses some of its assumptions, that doesn't make the conclusion any less true. It just means that the user may have done more work than he strictly needs to do.

Comment: Finally got it. Thanks so much.